# Split digits with spaces by groups of 3 in java

Tags: java, split, numbers

Is there any way to split a double number in java so that all groups of 3 digits are splitted with a space and only 2 digits after a comma are appeared? It's easy to separate them with a comma:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
df.format(number);
```

So that `235235.234` turns into `234,234.23`

What I need is `234 234.23`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe the comma in your format string isn't *really* a comma - it's just the grouping symbol in the `DecimalFormatSymbols` you're using.

Try this:

```
// TODO: Consider specifying a locale
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00", symbols);
```

Or as an alternative for the last line:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
df.setGroupingSize(3);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: @Sergey Not really related with this question/answer, but there is a liitle known trick to improve the readability of numeric literals in java 7 and later, by using the `_` to separate groups. Example: `public final static long SUNDIAMETER = 1_390_000_000L;`

Comment: I'm getting the error `No signature of method: java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ ]
Possible solutions: setGroupingSeparator(char), getGroupingSeparator()` :(

Comment: @PrintlnParams: Well my code only calls `setGroupingSeparate` *with* a `char`, so I'm not sure what code you're using...